# Problema obtener el max de una lista de registros Linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Estoy tratando de pasar un query a Linq, pero no me está dando el mayor.

El query es:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE
  WHEN RETIROFECHA IS NOT NULL AND RETIROCONFIRMADO = 'S' THEN RETIROFECHA
  ELSE fechaActual END) FECHA
FROM VINCULACION_TPP
WHERE CODEMPLEADO = codEmpleado
```

Estuve haciendo una prueba y consegui esto, pero de igual no me lo está dando:

```
(from VI in _contexto.Vinculacion_MPP
 where VI.CODEMPLEADO == codEmpleado
 select new
 {
    fecha = (VI.RETIROFECHA != null & VI.RETIROCONFIRMADO == 'S') ? VI.RETIROFECHA : DateTime.Now
 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar esta consulta, la cual es idéntica a la tuya pero al final se aplica el **operador Max**:

```
var fecha = (from VI in _contexto.Vinculacion_MPP
             where VI.CODEMPLEADO == codEmpleado
             select new
             {
                fecha = (VI.RETIROFECHA != null & VI.RETIROCONFIRMADO == 'S') ? 
                VI.RETIROFECHA : 
                DateTime.Now
             }).Max();
```

También puedes probar esta otra, donde se ordena descendentemente teniendo en cuenta la fecha y se selecciona el primer elemento de la lista ya ordenada:

```
var fecha = (from VI in _contexto.Vinculacion_MPP
             where VI.CODEMPLEADO == codEmpleado
             select new
             {
                fecha = (VI.RETIROFECHA != null & VI.RETIROCONFIRMADO == 'S') ? 
                VI.RETIROFECHA : 
                DateTime.Now
             }).OrderByDescending(f => f.fecha).FirstOrDefault();
```

También puedes probar esta consulta donde utilizas una **expresión lambda** aplicando directamente el **operador Max**:

```
var fecha = VI.Max(v => (v.RETIROFECHA != null && v.RETIROCONFIRMADO == 'S') ?
                   v.RETIROFECHA :
                   DateTime.Now
                  );
```

Comment: Tenia la duda si colocar el Max() al final para conseguirlo, pero me lo solucionaste. Muchas gracias!